# Ceiling fan electrical box missing female screw holes

Tags: electrical, junction-box

I have an existing electrical box that appears to support ceiling fan installation but it is missing the 2 female screw holes I'm used to finding in these boxes.

[image: Ceiling fan electrical box]

Is there some sort of intermediate piece that attaches to the two existing post screws?  I cannot find any brand or model information in the interior.

Answer (score 4):

Based on those bolts, I would assume this is a retrofit ceiling fan brace box [like this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0002YUS5G), but I have no idea where the screw ears would have gone.  Even boxes that aren't meant to have a fixture or fan hanging from them should have screw ears to attach a cover to the box.

I would just pull that one out and replace it with a new ceiling fan brace kit.  They are cheap enough that trying to find parts for yours doesn't make much sense.

Of course maybe this is an odd style that I haven't seen before...

Answer (score 4):

I have never seen a box like this before and have to assume it's a manufacturing defect or a ticked off contractor. If you have access to an attic or crawl space above this, you can just remove it and the support bracket  and replace it with a different one. Otherwise remove the "u" bolt nuts, remove the box and look for a replacement similar to the one shown below.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a [Legrand 22200 retrofit box](https://www.legrand.us/passandseymour/reiker-fan-boxes/old-work-boxes/retrofit-braces/retrofit-braces/22200.aspx). They typically have a riveted screw on each side, but I don't see either.

You might not need to buy a whole new brace, however. Take it down and go to the hardware store. They should have a box that will work with it as-is.

Answer (score 4):

They make cross braces for dealing with things like this.  It's a bar of metal with threaded holes at the appropriate places, then two plain holes for going into those studs.

I gather the studs are short of the edge of the box.   To attach to those, screw a coupler onto the studs, this being a length of hex stock threaded on the inside.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The 10-32 screws support the fan. The fan itself usually has the bracket and cover that matches, I have used them on new construction.